# Print HTML & CSS via PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a user registration and login form which has various error/success messages. I am trying to put my error box html code around each error message but am having a bit of difficulty.

The html for the error box is:

```
<div class="alert alert-info alert-login"> *error message here* <div>
```

My PHP looks like this:

```
$msg = 'login failed';
```

I have tried the following:

```
$msg = '<div class=\"alert alert-info alert-login\">login failed<br></div>';
```

However this did not work, is anyone able to shed some light as to why and how I am able to fix this? The message is showing but the div styling does not.
Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using single quotes to encapsulate the string, you don't need to escape the double ones, so use:

```
$msg = '<div class="alert alert-info alert-login">login failed<br></div>';
```

More about strings and single quotes: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: I endeavour to please! Please click the checkmark to mark this answer as accepted if you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use slashes if the apostrophes are different.

```
$msg = '<div class="alert alert-info alert-login">login failed<br></div>';
       ^           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ' can also use for " in html.
You can code like this in this case.

```
$msg = "<div class='alert alert-info alert-login'>login failed<br></div>";
```